# Conditionally assign values to NAs in a column based on comparison of multiple observations in another column, within a grouped data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

Below is my example data frame (code and output), which includes the relevant columns from my actual data frame:

```
example <- data.frame(contig=c("Contig1", "Contig1", "Contig1", "Contig1", "Contig1", "Contig2", "Contig2", "Contig2", "Contig2", "Contig2", "Contig2", "Contig2", "Contig3", "Contig3", "Contig3", "Contig3", "Contig3", "Contig3", "Contig3", "Contig3"),
                  pos=c(500, 650, 750, 1000, 2000, 500, 4100, 5000, 5300, 6100, 6400, 7500, 600, 3800, 4500, 5000, 5500, 6100, 7000, 8000),
                  av=c(NA, 12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20, NA, NA, 25, NA, NA, 55, NA, NA, NA, 56, NA, NA))
```

[image: example data frame]

Currently only some observations have a value for `av` whereas many are `NA`. I would like to assign values of `av` to replace the `NA`s, and have two different, separate methods that I would like to use to do this, so that I can compare the results of the two methods later, but I don't know how to implement either method.

First, I would like to replace `NA`s such that, within a `contig` (i.e. the data frame should be grouped by `contig`), if the `pos` of an observation with an `NA` for `av` is within 1000 of the `pos` of an observation with an `av` value, then the `NA` will be replaced by that value of `av`. Any `NA`s without a `pos` within 1000 of another `pos`(with an `av` value) on the same `contig` will remain as `NA`.

Second, I would like to replace `NA`s without the condition of the `pos` being within 1000 of a `pos` with an `av` value, but still within `contig` groups. Many `contig` groups will only have one observation with an `av` value, so this `av` value can replace all the `NA`s within that `contig` group (I think `na.locf()` will do this). However, some `contig` groups have more than one observation with an `av` value, so for those I would like to assign the `NA`s the `av` value of the observation with the `pos` closer to its own `pos` value.

Below are the desired outputs of the two methods for the example data frame.

Method 1

[image: method1 output]

Method 2

[image: method2 output]

Answer (score 0):

Just put in the dataframe to impute. Change the method argument to "method1" or "method2". If the dataframe is not the same structure it will not work as I have references the columns by their index e.g. 1 for contig, 2 for pos and 3 for av.

```
impute_av = function(df, method){

  sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){

    if(is.na(df[i,3])){

      if(method == "method1"){
        y = df[df[,1] == df[i,1] & df[,2] < df[i,2] + 1000 & df[,2] > df[i,2] - 1000, 2:3, drop=F]
      } else if(method == "method2"){
        y = df[df[,1] == df[i,1], 2:3, drop=F]
      }

      y = y[!is.na(y[,2]),,drop=F]

      if(nrow(y) == 0){
        df[i,3]
      } else {
        y[which.min(abs(y[,1] - df[i,2])), 2]
      }

    } else df[i,3]

  })

}
```

Comment: When I run this, I get this error: `Error in Ops.data.frame(df[, 1], df[i, 1]) : 
  ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames`. My actual data frame has 7 columns and I have tried both changing the column numbers in your code (from 1,2,3, to 2,3,7 respectively) and rearranging the columns in my data frame so that the relevant columns are 1, 2 and 3, but get this same error both times